# Adjusting Atom-Beautify/JS-Beautify for Laravel Blade

Tags: php, atom-editor, laravel-blade, js-beautify, atom-beautify

I like to customize JS-Beautify in Atom to better format my blade files.

Our manual style looks like this:

```
{{--
  Template Name: Full Width Template
--}}
<!-- template-fullwidth -->

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  @while(have_posts()) 
    @php the_post() @endphp
    @include('sections.content-page')
  @endwhile
@endsection
```

JS-Beautify gives us this:

```
{{-- Template Name: Full Width Template
--}}
<!-- template-fullwidth -->
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
@while(have_posts())
@php the_post()
@endphp
@include('sections.content-page')
@endwhile
@endsection
```

I've tried configuring the .jsbeautifyrc file but with no luck.

I'd like to:

1. Preserve comment lines
2. Add an empty line before select directives [@extends, @section]
3. Indent lines inside a @section directives
4. Indent items inside @while and @if
5. Keep @php code and @endphp on one line

Or failing all of that have some sort of readable, well-formated code and not just a long list of directives.

Can this be done?

Comment: have you found any solution!

Comment: Nope. But I have not looked in a while.